# Is it possible to use natbib's \citep and thebibliography at the same time?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Excuse me for this question, I am a beginner in latex.

I defined the package `natbib` to be able to use `\citep{}`. On the other hand, I used `\begin{thebibliography}{}` to prepare my references which gives me the error `! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`

I know that when using the package natbib, I should use bibtex for references but I prefer the first method. Is there a way to use the `\citep` and `\begin{thebibliography}{}` in the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use `natbib`'s citation commands and a hand-built `thebibliography` environment at the same time?

Yes. You must write the optional argument of each `\bibitem` directive, i.e., what's enclosed by `[` and `]`, in a specific `natbib`-compatible format; see the documentation of `natbib`. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep{jon90} \citet{jon90}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem[Jones et~al.(1990)]{jon90} some text

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of expanding your answer slightly. Feel free to revert...